# Cómo funcionaría facet_wrap con estos datos?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

Tengo este conjunto de datos

[image: Datos]

Donde 1,2,3,4,5,6,18953... representan individuos, y cada valor registrado frente a mi variable Temp, es lo que quiero graficar. Al final quisiera tener un plot del tipo

[image: plot]

Pero no sé cómo debería organizar mi df inicial para conseguirlo. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso hay que trabajar las personas como factores para facilitar la construcción del gráfico respectivo.

Se crea los datos iniciales

```
nFilas <- 20
nPersonas <- 6
set.seed(20190320)

df<-data.frame(temp=seq(-3.3,14.7,length.out = nFilas))
for (i in 1:nPersonas) df[,i+1]  <- runif(nFilas, -125,900)
colnames(df)<-c("temp",1:nPersonas)
df

         temp          1          2           3         4          5          6
1  -3.3000000 749.393547  620.53022  701.876350 732.85395 675.378994  -97.00110
2  -2.3526316 111.243712  307.46048  557.621336 420.64176 336.474029  241.07638
3  -1.4052632 344.805670  753.01664  872.247881  58.67846 109.955826  425.41611
4  -0.4578947 807.501368  611.25050  -90.042860  76.60173 114.418069  478.18556
5   0.4894737 362.744458  375.33515  -67.027906  36.14731 812.593395   43.94705
6   1.4368421  -7.997008  569.20070  682.283007 706.41169 719.779506   67.65650
7   2.3842105 798.996957  486.56962  534.439616  60.96042 836.951559  324.25746
8   3.3315789 365.202166  476.65600  778.492958 259.46762 149.504419  558.08466
9   4.2789474 423.757121 -105.13022  305.615076 276.37699 675.604828  -93.02579
10  5.2263158 858.999905  888.33208  178.035627 -56.49503  31.490936  272.50199
11  6.1736842 702.225382  661.54573  468.975455  32.53351 129.200682  198.07859
12  7.1210526 788.340562  151.59768  869.736386 190.63376 840.412707  -16.24743
13  8.0684211 731.527003  105.83991  515.505558 821.80225 460.490959   24.66595
14  9.0157895 893.841653   38.50499  800.174486 394.89320 652.378358  671.82621
15  9.9631579 654.063094  782.19705 -115.509606 143.34723 -73.224599 -107.25909
16 10.9105263 306.440000  813.58694  406.473660 357.34358 632.121997   77.87745
17 11.8578947 257.475579  -70.30068  147.640960 267.72295   6.916414  209.82261
18 12.8052632 288.156559  894.87291  -96.419952 835.29815 786.817061  834.42646
19 13.7526316 873.778338   35.06122  107.650263 613.49948 231.892993  331.12362
20 14.7000000 337.672819  568.45932    5.217365 264.39315 878.271935   54.67719
```

Luego hay que convertir las columnas de las `personas` en filas, para ello se emplea la función `gather` del paquete `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)

# solo las columna de las personas se convierten en filas
# en tal sentido el rango es 2:ncol(df)
longDF <- df %>% gather(persona, valor, 2:ncol(df))
longDF[1:24,]

         temp persona      valor
1  -3.3000000       1 749.393547
2  -2.3526316       1 111.243712
3  -1.4052632       1 344.805670
4  -0.4578947       1 807.501368
5   0.4894737       1 362.744458
6   1.4368421       1  -7.997008
7   2.3842105       1 798.996957
8   3.3315789       1 365.202166
9   4.2789474       1 423.757121
10  5.2263158       1 858.999905
11  6.1736842       1 702.225382
12  7.1210526       1 788.340562
13  8.0684211       1 731.527003
14  9.0157895       1 893.841653
15  9.9631579       1 654.063094
16 10.9105263       1 306.440000
17 11.8578947       1 257.475579
18 12.8052632       1 288.156559
19 13.7526316       1 873.778338
20 14.7000000       1 337.672819
21 -3.3000000       2 620.530216
22 -2.3526316       2 307.460481
23 -1.4052632       2 753.016645
24 -0.4578947       2 611.250503
```

Y de aquí se puede emplear `lattice` o `ggplot2` para conseguir el gráfico en grid

En el caso del primero sería de la siguiente forma

```
library(lattice)

dimFilGrid <- 2

# el operador %% me da el resto de una division
# se le emplea para que calcen la dimension del grid
dimColGrid <- (ncol(df)-ncol(df)%%dimFilGrid)/dimFilGrid

xyplot(valor~temp | factor(persona), 
       data = longDF, type='b',
       layout = c(dimColGrid,dimFilGrid)
      )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de `ggplot` es más sencillo fijar el número de filas del `grid`, asimismo `facet_wrap` puede trabajar con `persona` como si fuera un factor, sólo hay que anteponerle el caracter `~` para ello.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=longDF , mapping=aes(x=temp,y=valor))+
    geom_line()+
    facet_wrap( ~ persona, nrow = 2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente `ggplot` permite empezar ha ordenar el `grid` desde la parte superior izquierda, se puede lograr lo mismo con `lattice` pero requiere de pasos adicionales, en tal sentido, considero que esto, ya escapa a la pregunta publicada originalmente.

> **Nota:**
>   Se menciona que a `persona` se le da tratamiento de factor, dentro de las funciones respectivas, no obstante al aplicar `str(longDF)` se observa que la variable `persona` no es un factor como tal en **R** base, sino que los paquetes empleados lo convierten internamente en un factor, a efecto de lograr los resultados presentados.

```
str(longDF)

'data.frame':   120 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ temp   : num  -3.3 -2.353 -1.405 -0.458 0.489 ...
 $ persona: chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ valor  : num  749 111 345 808 363 ...
```

Comment: Agregue una nota al final, para indicar porque `persona` es un factor a pesar de que `str(longDF)` indique que es del tipo `character`

Comment: Muchas gracias! La herramienta gather era la clave y la desconocía, gracias! Una última cosa: En mi caso quiero graficar 15 "personas", y quisiera que los gráficos aparecieran en orden ascendente, pero lo que hace es ponerme primero el 1, luego el 10,11,12,2... y no 1, 2, 3. Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola @Caro, una vez tengas el `data.frame` organizado con las `15 personas` antes de usar `ggplot2`, se tendría que emplear lo siguiente: **longDF<-within(longDF,
               persona <- ordered(persona, levels = rev(sort(unique(persona)))))** asimismo siento decir que esta expresión no basta en el caso de `lattice` ya que dicho paquete no se basa en la gramática de gráficos [(`gg...`)](https://books.google.com.co/books/about/The_Grammar_of_Graphics.html?id=NRyGnjeNKJIC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), en cambio `ggplot2` sí: `ggplo2=lattice+Rbase`